# Software to combine Springpad with Firefox/Chrome

Tags: web-browser, bookmark

I am using [Springpad](https://springpad.com/) to organize my notes and bookmarks. However, I’d like to combine the collected bookmarks in Springpad with Firefox/Chrome, to be displayed in the bookmarks bar.

Use cases:

1. Access bookmarks stored at Springpad easily using the browser’s bookmark bar.
2. Whenever I upgrade my Tor browser bundle, all the bookmarks from the bookmarks bar are lost. I would like to keep them.

Comment: Note that Springpad has shut down, so this question can't really be answered. [Meta discussion about what we should do in these cases.](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/how-should-we-handle-obsolete-questions)